# Background fixed on content with scroll

Tags: css

I don't know how to make my background fixed on my content with scroll...

I'd like to set a background fixed on the page and the cover property do the same thing, I get a margin...

My code :

```
.ui-container{
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    margin: 0 0 0 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    height: calc(100% - 71px); // 71px is the menu
}
```

My result :

[image]

**EDIT #1:**

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tonymx227/1b22k5d1/

Comment: Why don't you simply put `height:100%` to make it take all height?

Comment: what does removing the margin do? (as it looks like it's around 200px)

Comment: `background-position: 200px 71px` this is what I think you are trying..

Comment: `height: 100%;` does the same thing... And `background-position` too...

Comment: by any chance do you have a footer/navbar positioned at the bottom of the page? That 'Margin' could just be the navbar?

Comment: No I don't have any content at the bottom of the page. :/ Without scroll it works but when there is a large content with scroll the background gets a margin...

Comment: I suppose a small jsfiddle is possible for a bit of tinkering?

Comment: No sorry because it's a big project and too difficult to import on JSFiddle...

Comment: Trying `Background-size:cover` and `background-attachment:fixed` might help u but like every one suggesting JsFiddle might give a clear view of problem.

Comment: No doesn't work too... See above, EDIT #1 (JSFiddle)